# Converting monix.eval.Task to scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, monix

I’m trying to reuse some module that uses `monix.eval.Task` for async tasks.
My project uses `scala.concurrent.Future`.

I'm trying to understand the best way to convert it to `Future` with the least amount of damage.

The easiest way is to use an additional thread pool:

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

import scala.concurrent.Future

// Create a Monix Task
val monixTask: Task[String] = Task("Hello, Monix!")

// Convert the Task to a Future using toFuture
val scalaFuture: Future[String] = monixTask.toFuture
```

But I don't fully understand the performance implications.

1. I already have `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` defined in the project. What are the implications of adding the global `monix.execution.Scheduler`?
2. Where the tasks will actually be computed? With `ExecutionContext`  or `Scheduler`? I'm guessing it queue up on `Scheduler`, have a small overhead of conversion, and then run on `ExecutionContext`?

The given module simply uses `Task.deferFuture` on all the Future he receives.

The async tasks are IO tasks, having 300k~600k rpm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monix's default Scheduler delegates to the Scala default ExecutionContext, so if you were trying to avoid using that EC, you should define your own Scheduler instance that uses your custom EC. The Scheduler companion has a handful of `apply` methods defined for this purpose.

A Scheduler uses a `ScheduledExecutorService` for *scheduling* tasks, and an `ExecutionContext` for *running* the tasks. So if you pass your custom ExecutionContext to the `Scheduler.apply`, your tasks will run there.

A note about interop between `Task` and `Future`: a `Task` is lazy by nature. Constructing one does not run it. So when wrapping a Future-returning expression as a `Task`, the `deferFuture` takes the expression in call-by-name style, so that the Future will not actually be constructed and started until that Task is told to run.

Since you mentioned the Tasks contain IO (I'm assuming you mean in the "I/O" sense, not `cats.effect.IO`), it might be appropriate to set up a separate dedicated thread pool (ExecutionContext) for performing IO-bound operations, so those don't block your CPU-bound "compute" threads. See `Scheduler.io` as a starting point for that.